# IIS serving old CSHTML file even after clearing many caches

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, caching, iis-10, windows-server-2019

We are deploying an ASP.NET Framework MVC web application to an on-premises Windows server 2019 data center running IIS 10.0. We’ve previously deployed this same application to an on-premises Windows 2012 server running IIS 7.5 without any issues. However, since migrating to the new server, changes to a specific CSHTML file are not reflected in the running website.

### Details

- The web application is running on the same IIS server as other ASP.NET applications, not of which are experiencing this issue.
- This web application is the only MVC application on the server, so the issue might only affect MVC applications.
- The only change to the CSHTML file is the `href` attribute of an anchor tag. When examining the file in the browser, it does not use the updated `href`.
- The failing file is named `/views/cms/about.cshtml`
- There is another file named `/views/home/about.cshtml`
- After modifying several `CmsController` actions (`About`, `Foo`, and `Bar`), we've successfully changed the deployed behavior for `/cms/foo` and `/csm/bar`, but not `/cms/about`, so the `About` action isn't being invoked; thus, IIS appears to be caching the result of the **/cms/about route**, not the **/Views/Cms/About.cshtml file**

We are currently corresponding with a Microsoft consultant, but even they are stumped thus far. Any ideas are appreciated.

### What we’ve tried thus far

- The cshtml files on the server are correct; thus, it is not a deployment issue
- The “last modified” date of all files in the site folder – including binaries – are correct
- Neither clearing the browser cache nor accessing the site from a private browsing context fixes the issue; thus, it is not a client-side issue
- The server’s localhost serves the old page; thus, it is not a network issue
- Changes to static resources are reflected in the browser; thus, the issue only affects CSHTML files
- The old version of the file is served even after deleting or renaming the file; thus, a cache is most likely involved somewhere
- Deleting the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder does not resolve the issue.
- Recycling the app pool in IIS does not fix the issue.
- Restarting the application in IIS does not fix the issue.
- Restarting the IIS server does not fix the issue.
- Disabling output caching does not fix the issue.
- Though this problem is like [this other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1273318/11110116), the solutions listed did not work.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61293266/11110116) sounds similar but is not a long-term solution.
- added 6/22/2023: re-deploying the application does not fix the issue

After each of these attempts, the server continued to serve the old CSHTML file.

Comment: Does the same happen when you use private browsing/incognito mode on your browser? Have you tried redeploying the project?

Comment: @samwu I've updated my initial post to clarify. We've already tried those solutions, and have ruled out the possibility of a client side problem. Redeploying doesn't work, but I'll be checking today if something is going wrong with the deployed artifacts. Good ideas though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

As it turns out, the admins can override the content of webpages so they don't have to open tickets when they need grammar- or other small changes.
Whenever requests were made to the `/cms/about` route, the app saw the content override, then rendered that instead of `/cms/about.aspx`.
We resolved the issue by modifying the overriding content.